# Last edit of event? Android Calendar provider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I have a calendar sync programm, My main problem is find LAST-EDIT of  EVENT. Do we have meta-data for this. I need this value to sync, I find it a week now, I guess Google not support Calendar API fully. Does anyone meet this problem before?

Thanks for your reading

Answer (score 0):

I come back, I after a week reasearch I found out a way, that is : A new event create, delete, modified must use `asSyncAdapter`

```
public static Uri asSyncAdapter(Uri uri, String account, String accountType) {
    return uri
            .buildUpon()
            .appendQueryParameter(android.provider.CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true")
            .appendQueryParameter(Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, account)
            .appendQueryParameter(Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountType)
            .build();
}
```

//For example:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, calendar_Id);
    values.put(Events.ORGANIZER, username);
    values.put(Events.TITLE, summary);
    values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, description);
    values.put(Events.DTSTART, GlobalVar.convertTIMEtomilisecond(dtstart));
    values.put(Events.DTEND, GlobalVar.convertTIMEtomilisecond(dtend));
    values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, timeZone);
    values.put(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, event_location);
    values.put(Events._SYNC_ID, uuid);
    values.put(Events.SYNC_DATA1, etag);
    values.put(Events.SYNC_DATA2, calendar.toString());
    Uri syncUri = CalendarProvider.asSyncAdapter(Events.CONTENT_URI, username, context.getResources().getString(R.string.ACCOUNT_TYPE));
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    cr.insert(syncUri, values);
```

//And get dirty event in here

```
cur = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"), null, Events.DIRTY+" = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(1)}, null);
    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
        int id = (int) cur.getLong(cur.getColumnIndex(Events._ID));
```

//And it works fine :P